# Proof of Hewitt-Savage-deFinetti Theorem using Diaconis-Freedman-Lions Approach

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following (time-pressing) issue. I want to use the Diaconis-Freedman Theorem to prove (in a constructive way) the Hewitt-Savage Theorem for finite, exchangeable sequences and I am stuck with the following equation to proof:

For $\mu^{(N)}$ as N-th marginal of the symmetric measure $\mu$ (for simplicity reasons) on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes \mathbb{N}}$ (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $dx$), i.e. the exchangeable measure (law) induced by an infinite sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, the author wrote for $k < N, \phi$ as continuous, bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^k$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \phi(x_1,\dots,x_k) \rho^{\otimes k}_{emp, Z}(d(x_1,\dots,x_k))\Big)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \phi(z_1,\dots,z_k)\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k)) + O(N^{-1})
$$

where $\rho^{\otimes k}_{emp, Z}$ should denote the $k$-product measure of the empirical measure induced by $Z = (z_1,\dots,z_N)$, i.e.
$$
\forall B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}): \rho_{emp,Z}(B) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N \delta_{z_i}(B)
$$
for $\delta$ as Dirac mass.

I am struggeling to find the expression for the $O$-functional. Previously, I have  already shown that for $\Gamma_N$ as the space of all $N$-tuple $\gamma$ defined on the set $\{1,\dots,N\}$ (drawing with replacement), the following equation of measures on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ holds for given $(z_1,\dots,z_N)$:
$$
\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_N} N^{-N}\delta_{(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(N)})}(B_1,\dots,B_N) = \Big(N^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^N \delta_{z_i}\Big)^{\otimes N}(B_1,\dots,B_N)
$$
for $B_i \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

My approach of the equation is up until now the following: Using the equation above, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\underbrace{\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \phi(x_1,\dots,x_k) \rho^{\otimes k}_{emp, Z}(d(x_1,\dots,x_k))\Big)}_{=\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_N} N^{-k}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))} \mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N)) 
= \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_N} N^{-k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N))
$$
Then I wanted to rearrange the sum, s.t. I group all mappings $\gamma \in \Gamma_N$ together for which $\gamma(1)\neq \cdots \neq\gamma(k)$ (such that it acts as "draw $k$ without replacing from $\{1,\dots,N\}$") in order to get the following (using exchangeability of $\mu^{(k)}$)
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N)) \stackrel{?}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_1,\dots,z_k)\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))
$$
for all $\gamma \in \Gamma_N^* = \{\gamma \in \Gamma_N: \gamma(1) \neq \cdots \neq \gamma(k)\}$.

But then I get 
$$
\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_N} N^{-k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N)) = \Bigg(\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma^*_N} N^{-k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N))\Bigg) + \Bigg(\sum_{\gamma \notin \Gamma^*_N} N^{-k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N))\Bigg) \stackrel{s.a.}{=} \Bigg(\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma^*_N} N^{-k}\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_1,\dots,z_k)\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)  + \Bigg(\sum_{\gamma \notin \Gamma^*_N} N^{-k} \underbrace{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_{\gamma(1)},\dots,z_{\gamma(k)})\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k))\Bigg)\mu^{(N)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_N))\Bigg)}_{= M_\gamma} \stackrel{(*)}{=} N^{-k} \binom{N}{k} \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}\phi(z_1,\dots,z_k)\mu^{(k)}(d(z_1,\dots,z_k)) + \sum_{\gamma \notin \Gamma^*_N} N^{-k} M_\gamma
$$
To $(*)$: $|\Gamma_N^*| = \binom{N}{k}$ since it behaves like "draw $k$ from $N$ without replacing".

So that the factor for the first sum is already off.

Can someone please help me to get this proof done?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So you need to present this tomorrow?

Comment: It is the last proof of my thesis which is due on Monday.

Comment: Hey Newman, I have arrived to the same problem as you as well. May I know if you have solved the problem you had?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct in your last calculation. I'm reading the Diaconis-Freedman proof from the following [lecture to MathPhys in LMU](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~sorensen/Lehre/SoSe2015/Rougerie/deF-Munich_v2-May15.pdf) for De Finetti Theorems **page 31**.

In the DF proof, it states: By the symmetry of $\mu^{(n)}_N$, we obtain
$$
\tilde{\mu}^{(n)}_N = \frac{N(N-1)\cdots (N-n+1)}{N^n}\mu^{(n)}_N + v_n,
$$
where $v_n$ is a positive measure on some $\Omega^n$.

Then the rest of the proof for D-F theorem is elementary as shown in the page. (But it is not a sharp estimate)